# Python zip single list element

Tags: python

I have this:

```
t=[(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(11,22,33),(44,55,66)]
```

and want to get this :

```
[(1,4,11,44),(2,5,22,55),(3,6,33,66)]
```

How to do it in a pythonic way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use star(*). It can unpacking argument lists.

```
>>> zip(*t)
[(1, 4, 11, 44), (2, 5, 22, 55), (3, 6, 33, 66)]
```

For example:

```
>>> args = [3, 6]
>>> range(*args)            # It's equivalent to range(3, 6)
[3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: It might help to add an explanation of what the `*` syntax does

Comment: @inspectorG4dget The [python star operator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2921893/507762).